# Using conditional aggregation to place values into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which I created to report results. I am trying to get all of the results to show up on a single line. They are currently showing on each individual line. How could I go about getting all the data to show onto 1 row for each ID#?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
       WHERE  TABLE_NAME = N'PBI_TrendData_VW')
    DROP VIEW PBI_TrendData_VW
GO
Create view dbo.PBI_TrendData_VW as

     SELECT distinct 
    Orders.Ordno as [ID#],
    CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(100-convert(float,Results.rn2))) END [Moi],
    CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn2))) END [DM1],
    CASE WHEN Analyte = 'CP' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn1))) END [Protein]
 FROM   (((FOLDERS 
 INNER JOIN ORDERS ON FOLDERS.FOLDERNO=ORDERS.FOLDERNO) 
 INNER JOIN RESULTS ON ORDERS.ORDNO=RESULTS.ORDNO))
 WHERE  RESULTS.SA='Released'  
 GROUP BY ORDERS.ORDNO, Results.RN1, Results.Rn2, Results.Final, results.analyte

 GO
```

Current outcome:

```
|ID# | Moi | Dm1 | Protein |
|1   | 50  | Null|    Null |
|1   |Null | 50  |    Null |
|1   |Null | 50  |    22.4 |
|2   |Null | 25  |    Null |
|2   |75   |Null |    Null |
|2   |Null |Null |    32.4 |
```

Expected outcome:

```
|ID# | Moi | Dm1 | Protein |
|1   | 50  | 50  |    22.4 |
|2   |75   | 25  |    32.4 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want aggregation.  I think:

```
SELECT o.Ordno as [ID#],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(100-convert(float,Results.rn2))) END) as [Moi],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn2))) END) as [DM1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'CP' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn1))) END) as [Protein]
FROM FOLDERS f JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON f.FOLDERNO = o.FOLDERNO JOIN
     RESULTS r
     ON o.ORDNO = r.ORDNO
WHERE r.SA = 'Released'  
GROUP BY o.ORDNO;
```

I am not sure why you have multiple conversions in the `CASE`.  I'm leaving them with a note that they are probably not necessary.

Note that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

`SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` is almost never appropriate.  The columns in the `GROUP BY` should be keys that define what *one* row looks like in the result set.  In your case, `o.Ordno`.

Answer (score 2):

You're grouping by every returned value in your query, soit seems you don't know how `GROUP BY` works. You need to place an aggregate around your `CASE` expressions and remove the columns from the `GROUP BY`. At a guess:

```
SELECT Orders.Ordno as [ID#],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(100-convert(float,Results.rn2))) END) [Moi],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn2))) END) [DM1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'CP' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn1))) END) [Protein]
 FROM FOLDERS 
      INNER JOIN ORDERS ON FOLDERS.FOLDERNO=ORDERS.FOLDERNO
      INNER JOIN RESULTS ON ORDERS.ORDNO=RESULTS.ORDNO
 WHERE  RESULTS.SA='Released'  
 GROUP BY ORDERS.ORDNO;
```

Also, there's no need to wrap your objects in your `FROM` in parenthesis (`()`).

Answer (score 0):

use aggeragate function max()

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
       FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
       WHERE  TABLE_NAME = N'PBI_TrendData_VW')
    DROP VIEW PBI_TrendData_VW
GO
Create view dbo.PBI_TrendData_VW as

     SELECT  
    Orders.Ordno as [ID#],
   max( CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(100-convert(float,Results.rn2))) END) [Moi],
    max(CASE WHEN Analyte = 'DM1' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn2))) END) [DM1],
   max( CASE WHEN Analyte = 'CP' THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),(convert(float,Results.rn1))) END) [Protein]
 FROM   (((FOLDERS 
 INNER JOIN ORDERS ON FOLDERS.FOLDERNO=ORDERS.FOLDERNO) 
 INNER JOIN RESULTS ON ORDERS.ORDNO=RESULTS.ORDNO))
 WHERE  RESULTS.SA='Released'  
 GROUP BY ORDERS.ORDNO

 GO
```